# App crashing when starting new activity on button click

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener

I'm sorry for asking such a basic question, but I haven't found anything that could help me with this issue.
I'm trying to do something as simple as starting a new activity through a button click, but my application crashes whenever I click that button. Here is my code:

```
Button aboutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aboutButton);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This code is inside a function, which is in turn inside the `onCreate` function.
I've already tried putting this code straight into the `onCreate` function, but I got the same result.
Could you please tell me what I have done wrong?

PS.: My target activity is already declared at the manifest.

Error log :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ukdev.TestApp/com.ukdev.TestApp.About}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ukdev.TestApp/com.ukdev.TestApp.About}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Ok,Show About class code also

Comment: which line throws the NPE?

Comment: @rothloup: startActivity(intent) I guess, the problem is in About, and the question itself of course...

Comment: I debugged my code and I saw that my IDE has already created another Intent called intent, which has not been previously assigned, so when the application goes to the `startActivity(intent);` it pointed to the unassigned variable. Problem solved. Thanks @ρяσѕρєяK for prompting me to check the log and all others for the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `NullPointerException` came from an unassigned `intent` variable, which was called by the `startActivity(intent);` function.

Comment: what do you mean by unassigned intent ? It is assigned right there in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your About class has to extend Activity or AppCompatActivity, does yours?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { ...
```

if it does then we would just need the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes, it does extend, but thank you, my problem has just been solved.